# How to reverse all booleans in the list in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to reverse all my booleans in the list like this:

```
a=[True,False,True]
```

to this:

```
b=[False,True,False]
```

I tried

```
not a
```

But it gives only False to me.

Comment: `not a` is interpreted as `not bool(a)`, and `bool(a)` is `True` as `a` isn't empty (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Note that if `a` was a `numpy` array instead of a list, you could use `b = ~a`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use list comprehension  and `not` all the items

```
a=[True,False,True] 
b=[not c for c in a]
```

`not a` provided False due to the fact it checks list is empty since it isn't returns True so it is converted into false

```
a=[True]
not a
False
a=[False]
not a
True
```

Answer (score 5):

**You can do this with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):**

```
a = [True, False, True]
b = [not c for c in a]
```

What this does is basically analogous to:

```
a = [True, False, True]
b = []
for bool in a:
    b.append(not bool)
```

Or more generally:

```
new_list = [expression for item in a_list]
```

is essentially the same as:

```
new_list = []
for item in a_list:
    new_list.append(expression)
```

where `expression` can contain `item`

**The reason your version doesn't work** is that not can only operate on booleans and will implicitly convert anything passed to it to a boolean. [A non-empty list results in `True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and applying not to that gives you `False`

Answer (score 4):

You can `map` the `not` operator as a function to each item. And be sure to `import operator` as well:

```
map(operator.not_, [True, False, True]) # apply the not unary operator to each list item
```